# How to import Postman collection in SoapUI

Tags: import, postman, export, soapui

Requirement is to export Collection from Postman and import [run those APIs] in SOAPUI.
For this, I am simply exporting the collection and its coming with json extension.
I try to import that collection into SoapUI using 2 ways:

1. Directly importing: It seems like SoapUI is looking for XML files, not JSON. However, if I uploaded that file then, nothing is happening and folder with cross sign is displaying.
2. Creating REST project and providing URI. Here again nothing is working[APIs are not coming directly]

Also I tried to convert Collection JSON file to XML and upload it in SOAPUI. Even that is not working.

Is there any way in which I can directly import Collection into SOAPUI?

Comment: There is this https://www.soapui.org/docs/postman-collections/ , but I think that might be a paid feature.